# Restart a supervisor program without root

Tags: non-root-user, supervisord

I have a two-level supervisord system on Debian Linux:

In `/etc/supervisor/conf.d/opus-release.conf`

```
[program:opus]
user=opus
command=bash -c 'cd /home/opus/projects/XXX && supervisord -n -c ../conf/supervisord.conf'
```

and

```
[supervisord]
identifier=opus

[program:uwsgi]
command=uwsgi --ini=../conf/uwsgi.ini
```

in `/home/opus/projects/conf/supervisord.conf`.

I use `supervisorctl restart opus` to restart that project.

But `supervisorctl restart opus` works only under root.

What are good ways to restart the opus project without logging in as root?